# PDF creation tool that can handle Client-side view changes

Tags: asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to find a tool that can be used to create PDFs from websites. These websites all have Bootstrap based client side view settings, such as tabs, toggles, and paging. As such, there is no post-back to the server. I need to be able to create a pdf that is in the same state as the user sees it.

In my research, I have only been able to find tools that can create PDFs if given a URL, or if given a HTML string. Examples of these tools include [ActivePDF's Webgrabber](http://www.activepdf.com/index.php/products/webgrabber), and [EVO PDF](http://www.evopdf.com/). However, they are not able to generate the PDF's with the client-specific settings, but instead only see the default selections of a given page. It is not possible for me to do a post-back to the server, so I am looking for a tool that can create PDFs on the fly, with the dynamic settings intact. I am working in ASP.NET, and so I would like a tool that is .NET friendly as well. Lastly, I would prefer the tool to not be open-sourced.

Comment: Tool recommendation is off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: You don't have to do a postback to the server. Make an AJAX call, sending in the HTML or other data necessary to generate the PDF. The server side can then generate the PDF for you (which server side library to use is off topic for SO as paqogomez said). By the way, I can understand no logical reason for your "I would prefer the tool to not be open sourced" comment.

Comment: @mason, I get the impression that he doesnt have control over these servers, so full postback or partial postback w/ ajax it makes no difference.  OP wants to pdf the session's page and they want a tool to do it for them

Comment: @paqogomez I see why you might think that, but there could be other explanations. I guess we'll just have to hope ngwilliams provides more information.

Comment: @mason, regardless, OP is asking for a tool, not code.

Comment: The one thing the strikes me here is "I need to be able to create a pdf that is in the same state as the user sees it." That seems a bit odd to me. I would think a user on a small device like a phone does not want a PDF that is that size. I would think you would want the bootstrap model to flow to the size of the specified device -- being a PDF of "X/Y" dimension. That is what happens here http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf, format the pages on any device. They look different on different devices, the PDF is the same on all devices. "PDF" is treated like another device of certain size.

Comment: @mason, How do can I send the client-side HTML via AJAX? I think I could make that work, I've just never done it before. I need the tool to not be open sourced because it must comply with corporate standards and have existing support. I don't think this is against SO's rules, because I have done a fair amount of research, and have posted my problems, and am looking for suggestions on if such a tool exists.

Comment: @Kevin, I am not referencing the size of the device, I'm more talking about the state of tabs, data grids, and graphs.

Comment: Simply doing research doesn't make you allowed to ask for tool recommendations. Those questions simply aren't allowed. However, asking how to accomplish something is allowed, so I will make an example in a few minutes of how you could post data to the server via AJAX.

Comment: @ngwilliams .. OK, that site I sent you is much like that. The current state of everything is sent via AJAX to an external formatter, returning PDF using the CSS for styling. If you examine inside the Javascript, the core functionality is that it is scraping the current "look" atthe time of formatting by resolving all the CSS styles and user clicks and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a proper solution here would be to take data from your client side, post it via AJAX (not an ASP.NET postback!) and then process it on the server side to generate the PDF. Since you haven't given much detail, I'm going to assume we don't need to send over all the HTML, but rather values that were entered via a form.

```
<script>
function postDataToServer(){
    var itemId = $("#ItemIdTB").val();
    var quantityOrdered = $("#QuantityTB").val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "GeneratePdfFromForm?itemId="+itemId+"&quantityOrdered="+quantityOrdered
    })
    .done(function(){alert("Success!");})
    .fail(function(){alert("Failure!");});
}
</script>
```

My answer is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which is a JavaScript library that simplifies [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and DOM manipulation. However, this technique is doable with other JavaScript libraries (or even without a library).

On the server side, let's have an [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) function that can handle that AJAX Post.

```
[Route("GeneratePdfFromForm")]
public static void GeneratePdfFromForm(string itemId, int quantityOrdered)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Received itemId {0} and quantity {1}", itemId,   quantityOrdered);
    byte[] pdf = GeneratePDF(itemId, quantityOdered); //you'll need a function called GeneratePDF that can generate your PDF based on the parameters, probably using a library like iTextSharp.
    //now do you want with the PDF byte array
}
```

So that's how you'd generate the PDF. You *could* return it from the `GeneratePdfFromForm()` function back to the client. But since that's potentially a long running task, you should probably implement it in the background using something like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), then when the PDF is ready you'd present it to the client for download (perhaps using [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) or [jQuery AJAX polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) to alert the client of when the PDF is ready).

I was passing data from the client side to the server side via query string. You could instead create a class to represent the parameters for your PDF generation, then pass that form the client side to the server side via jQuery AJAX's `data` parameter.

If you really want to post the entire HTML from the client side to the server, you could so something like this:

```
var html=$("html").html();
$.ajax({
    url: <your url here>,
    data: html,
    contentType: "text/html"
});
```

However, I'm willing to bet the actual HTML isn't what you care about for generating the PDF, but rather the selected values from some client side form. The actual HTML would include *everything* on the client side, including navigation menus, scripts etc. You could post a subset of the HTML using a different selector (ex: `$("#OrderDiv").html()`), which is a technique some people use to generate PDF's. But I think it's much cleaner to decouple your HTML intended for the browser from the way the PDF is generated, so that changes to your site don't mess up the PDF. You can then u[se the PDF creating library's capabilities to build the PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx) rather than using HTML.